# How do dialetheists determine which contradiction is true?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-logic, paradox

I have been reading a lot about dialetheism lately. I know for a fact that dialetheists do not believe that every contradiction is true. (Surely there is a difference between asserting that Liar is true and 'Priest does karate and Priest does not do karate' is true)

In particular, it is my impression that Priest argues in *The Logic of Paradox* that only contradictions caused by self-referring paradoxes are true.

I would like confirmation/reference for the following:

1. Is it true that dialetheists believe that the only true contradictions are the ones that are caused by self-reference? And is self-reference the only criterion that results in true contradiction?
2. What does Priest think about allegedly-non-self-referring paradox like the Yablo paradox? Does he think it is true? If so, in virtue of what?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1) No, self-reference paradoxes are just one example. Others include statements with vague predicates (e.g. 50 grains are and are not a heap), about transitional states, legal collisions, etc., see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/#OtheMotiForDial). 2) Priest argued that Yablo's paradox is essentially self-referential, and not much different from the Liar, see [his paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.626.8312), so he does classify its sentences as true contradictions. Definitely non-self-referential Zeno's paradoxes are a more distinctive example

Comment: @Conifold Thank you that's really helpful, appreciate it!